# Products aren't detected if CSV importer are used

Tags: plugins, csv

I created a plug to import a CSV personalized.

The problem is that a plugin to create animation doesn't detect these products until I open the product on backend and update it.

Is there a way to emulate by code the click on update product?

Comment: You'll probably need to check with the author of the ecommerce plugin, as this is not WordPress-core-specific. If you still want to try to find help here, please post your relevant code.

Comment: Yeah I know but I'd like to know if there is a way to perform the same process as when someone clicks on update post and making this by script.

I tried with update_post, but it didn't work. 

It must be a way to perform a manual click operation by code. I'm here to ask if someone can help me, not to ask help to solve problem of the plugin.